# Laravel query builder does not return data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, postgresql-9.3

I have a query builder which for some reason returns null even though there is data in the table and I've confirmed this by getting the sql generated by the query builder and running it in HeidiSQL and sure enough there was data.

The following is the code:

```
$billSource = DB::table('trea.audit_bill_master')
    ->select('source')
    ->where('fin_year', $fin_year)
    ->where('bill_no', $val)
    ->where('trea_code', $trea_code)
    ->first();
```

and here is the generated SQL:

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "query" => "select "source" from "trea"."audit_bill_master" where "fin_year" = ? and "bill_no" = ? and "trea_code" = ? limit 1"
    "bindings" => array:3 [
      0 => "2021-2022"
      1 => "146"
      2 => "20"
    ]
    "time" => 1.14
  ]
]
```

I'm using postgres 9.3 as my database and laravel version 5.8

Comment: do you have any errors? connection or etc ?

Comment: No, when I dd $billSource it just gives out null @dılosürücü

Comment: try  set connection as such,
DB::connection('postgresql')->select()->foo()->bar()

Comment: change to  DB::table('audit_bill_master')

Comment: changing trea.audit_bill_master to simply audit_bill_master have no effect @Davit

Comment: that didn't do anything @dılosürücü

Comment: if you do `dd(DB::getPdo())`, is the `attributes.driver_name` of the resulting object pgsql? Try `dd(config('database.default'))` and `dd(config('database.connections.'.config('database.default')))` as well and make sure the information is correct.